# Disk is full, but can't find which folder take space

Tags: linux, disk

I'm trying to find out which folder in my VPS take the most of disk usge, the result of df -h command show that my disk storage has 40GB and I used 38 Gb.

But when I calculate the size of root folder using ncdu (using command: ncdu /), it show that I only used 8.9 Gb:
Can anyone help me to figure out which files/folders take nearly 30 Gb of my disk

Comment: Perhaps (but unlikely) some daemon has a huge temporary file (i.e has `open`-ed a file later `unlink`-ed). Then rebooting your VPS might help.

Comment: Try `find / -size +5000` to find big files....

Comment: Thank you a lots, after I reboot my VPS, the total disk usage is reduce to 9GB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this command:

```
du -cks *|sort -rn|head
```

This will list the 10 largest subdirectories of the current directory you're in. Then you can `cd` into the largest subdirectory and run the command again to see the sizes of the sub-subdirectories, and so on.

Source: https://serverfault.com/a/25045/297452

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an openfile issue.

try

```
lsof +L1 <path to dir>
```